# what is the behavior of Spark when Hive enable hive.spark.dynamic.partition.pruning

Tags: apache-spark, hive, bigdata

I have a Hive server running with Spark as its execution engine, I am wondering how enabling hive.spark.dynamic.partition.pruning can affect the queries?

Here is the description in Hive docs:

**hive.spark.dynamic.partition.pruning**

*"When true, this turns on dynamic partition pruning for the Spark engine, so that joins on partition keys will be processed by writing to a temporary HDFS file, and read later for removing unnecessary partitions."*

I thought that when seeing a partition filter in a query, Spark optimizer will not read partitions that do not match filter conditions. But the term "joins on partition keys will be processed by writing to a temporary HDFS file, and read later for removing unnecessary partitions" is making me so confused.